# Firebase: Does it matter how you push a reference

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

If I want to push a data base node in the real time database called (messages):

It have this structure:

```
     messages
     |
     current_id
     |
     user_id
     |
     push_id1
     |
     push_id2
```

Now if I want to push into messages/current_id/user_id

Then does it matter

if I do this:

```
     my_ref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("messages").child(current_id).child(user_id).push();
```

or this:

```
    my_ref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().push();
```

If yes. Then how does it differ?

**EDIT**

So I will explain how I used my code according to franks suggestion

so I got the push id from the first snippet frank suggested:

```
    String push_id= my_ref.getkey();
```

then I did this to multi update 2 locations

first location: messages/ current_id/ user_id

second location: messages/ user_id/ current_id

```
    Map message_map=new HashMap();
    message_map.put("messages/current_id/user_id/"+ push_id, "some value"); 

    Map message_map_2=new HashMap();
    message_map_2.put("messages/user_id/current_id" + push_id, "some_value");

     root_ref.updateChildren(message_map);
     root_ref.updateChildren(message_map_2);
```

I noticed that at location 2 push ids are not sorted normally (not sorted in order).

But at location 1 they are sorted normally.

Dont ask me why I split the multipath update.....its for security rules reasons.

Comment: The key is generated when you call `push()`. The first 8 characters are based on the (offset corrected) timestamp at that time, not of the time you actually write. That's how the system works. If the order is not what you expect, it is likely on how you call the API. Please see if you can reproduce in a single, isolated snippet of code that anyone of use can run.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen if the push ids are unique...then does this mean that when I add new key data to the database it should place it under the older keys.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I dont know if I can say that it seems to be a bug in the real time databse.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen if I add A then B then C to the database at node X.....then I expect to see X / A / B / C in the database ....... but this is not the case....is it normal?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen as an example you can try, if you add users in a users node based on the uid generated by auth......eventhough uids are unique, users are not added properly in order under each other....instead they are randomly inserted under users node.

Comment: I've never seen `push` IDs from a single client be out of order. While it's always possible there is a bug, that part of the SDKs has been largely unmodified for years now. But from your descriptions I can't reproduce it. If you can reproduce the problem in a [single snippet of code that I can run](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I'll gladly do that.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen pease check by your self adding different users with different uids using auth and you will see that they are randomly added....

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I am trying to give you a simple way for you to test this issue.......please do the following and you will detect the issue......make a button that adds push ids to a certain node....click it 4 times you should get 4 push ids under each other......now change the code of the button and make it add (1) instead of a push id to the same ref.......you will see that (1) is added before the 4 push ids, when it should be under them.

Comment: What does *not sorted normally (not sorted in order).* mean? i.e. in what order do you expect them to be sorted vs what order are they? Can you post your Firebase structure (update your question) and then describe what the issue is? You can get your structure from the Firebase console->Export JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `ref.push()` on any `DatabaseReference` essentially does two things:

1. Create a new ID that is statistically guaranteed to be unique, based on the current timestamp of the client and a lot of randomness to make it unique.
2. Create a new `DatabaseReference` point to `ref.child(newId)`.

---

This

```
 my_ref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("messages").child(current_id).child(user_id).push();
```

Creates a reference to a new location under `/messages/$current_id/$user_id`.

---

This:

```
my_ref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().push();
```

Creates a reference to a new location under the root.

---

Since you want a new child under `/messages/$current_id/$user_id`, you need the first snippet.

Note that neither snippet actually writes any data yet, which requires you to call `setValue(...)` or `updateChildren(...)`.

Comment: I used the first snippet, then I got the push key that should be random everytime. And I used the push key in a multipath update to the messages node...I noticed that the push key is added before the last push id and not after it,,,,,the new push id is added before the last push id under messages and not after it....

Comment: Why is that happening?

Comment: In other words push ids are not being added in order.

Comment: I added some more explanation of how `push()` works. But without seeing the code that created that situation it's hard to say what happened. Please see if you can [create a minimal, complete verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Eventhough they are unique random ids, firebase doesnt seem to always add them under each other.